# how to install two python package versions in different anaconda environments?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to use keras 1.0 and keras 2.0 at the same time, I tried to create two environments in anaconda: keras1 and keras2. 
I install keras1.0 in keras1, when I change the environment to keras2, I found the keras' version is 1.0, and I upgrade the keras to 2.0, then the keras' version became 2.0 in environment keras1.
What should I do to use the two versions at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues with Anaconda environments - pip will install to the environment in which you're 'logged in', so you need to be very careful about which environment you're in when you use pip.

If I were you, I would pip uninstall the packages in both environments, and methodically install keras in each, as having two different versions in two different environments will not be an issue.

Comment: Also, please prefer using `conda install` rather than `pip install` wherever possible. `conda` does a much better job interacting with its own environments and managing dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will follow these methods.